# In cnosdb, is there any rule in the use of equal sign and space?

Tags: cnosdb

In cnosdb
'create tenant' and 'alter tenant' only support equal signs;
'create database' and 'alter database' only support Spaces
I wonder if there are any special rules for this? If not, I hope it can be unified